# How to open and read resource forks in Obj-C

Tags: objective-c

I have an old (OS9) file containing a resource fork with "CODE" resources and i would like to read that from Obj-C.
I use something like:

```
NSFileHandle *codeFile=[NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingAtPath:myPath];
```

but see only the data fork!
Is there any simple solution for that?

I also tried to separate the resource fork with

```
"CpMac -r myFile newFile"
```

but get only the old file back?

Answer (score 4):

Opening the path

```
yourFile/..namedfork/rsrc
```

gives you access to the resource fork of "yourFile". Alternatively, you can use `getxattr()`,
because the resource fork is stored as an extended attribute named "com.apple.ResourceFork".