# Check for resource fork in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, xcode6, file-forks

How do i check whether a file exists with resource fork or not?

> Note : With out using the API's of CarbonCore->Resources.h, Since they
>   are deprecated.

I will be able to open the file where there exist resource fork or not. But i need to check whether the resource fork exists or not. This is what exactly i'm looking for.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to open and read resource forks in Obj-C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19400043/how-to-open-and-read-resource-forks-in-obj-c)

Comment: @Darren, not a duplicate, testing whether the fork exists is not the same as actually reading the fork.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use getattrlist or fgetattrlist passing ATTR_FILE_RSRCLENGTH in the attrList parameter. see the [man page for getattrlist](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man2/getattrlist.2.html).

Comment: Thank you geowar, that answers my question

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively

```
BOOL hasResourceFork = getxattr("/path/To/file", "com.apple.ResourceFork", NULL, 0, 0, 0) != -1;
```

That requires

```
#include <sys/xattr.h>
```

Answer (score 1):

For those who want to get the actual resource fork length, here's the code:

```
#include <sys/attr.h>

struct attrlist attrlist = {0};
attrlist.bitmapcount = ATTR_BIT_MAP_COUNT;
attrlist.fileattr    = ATTR_FILE_RSRCLENGTH;
typedef struct __attribute__((__packed__)) {
    uint32_t size;
    off_t forkSize;
} result_t;
result_t result = {0};
if (getattrlist (filepath, &attrlist, &result, sizeof(result), 0) == 0) {
    assert(sizeof(result)==result.size); // makes sure we got the struct right
    // now we find the rsrc fork size in result.forkSize
}
```