# Creating and writing HFS+ forks

Tags: objective-c, hfs+, alternate-data-stream

I'm writing an app that needs to store an alternate version of a file. Ideally, I'd like it to be transparent for the user - so I avoid to create another file along the original one.

Fortunately, I know from Amit Singh's website ([Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20200205220252/http://osxbook.com/software/hfsdebug/fragmentation.html)) that an HFS+ could have an `“arbitrary number of forks”`. If you don't know what it is, I'd recommend to read the previous link.

So, I'm happy as I know I could create a fork in the file - I can store my alternate version & the user doesn't get bothered by another file (that is likely to get deleted because `“WTF is that !?”`).

Now, I'd like to know how I'm supposed to create & write to that fork - programmatically, not using any command-line tool. I saw this question ([How to open and read resource forks in Obj-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19400043/how-to-open-and-read-resource-forks-in-obj-c?lq=1)) but it didn't get properly answered.

Thanks in advance !